# HttpSessionState as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the highest class in the hierarchy I can use to pass HttpSessionState as a parameter and add values to it?

For instance to a method like

```
public void MyMethod(IDictionary<string, object> input)
{
    input.Add("something", something);
}
```

I see that implements ICollection and IEnumerable, but that only allows me to read values, not add them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ICollection` is the best you can do.

You could wrap it in something that implements `IDictionary<string,object>` if you wanted it to be more convenient.

Comment: I have checked with Reflector. It implements IHttpSession, which is a separate collection. Sad.